# how can I stub the private method with reflection and then say the test code whenever it is called return `stubbed <X>` object?

Tags: java, mockito

To test below sample source code, I have written a bunch of code using Java Reflection. However, I could not manage to run, so I have deleted.

What I aim to do is basically reflect the `bar()` method of `CLASSZ`, and stub it so that whenever it is called in `foo()`, it will return stubbed instance of `Reader`. This stubbed instance then will send to `gar()` as a parameter.

At the end of the test code, I was planned to call `foo()` method and check return value of it with another `String`.

My question is "how can I stub the private method with reflection and then say the test code whenever it is called return stubbed `Reader` object?".

```
class CLASSZ{
    public String foo(){
        Reader reader = bar();
        String text = gar(reader);
        return text;
    }

    private Reader bar(){
       // do some operation related with Extractor; then create instance of Reader
       return new Reader(/*extractor related argument*/);
    }

    private String gar(Reader reader){
        // do something and return String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to convert your `private Reader bar()` to `protected`, then you can use [Mockito spying](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T))

Source:

```
package sw_stackoverflow;

class CLASSZ{
    public String foo(){
        Reader reader = bar();
        String text = gar(reader);
        return text;
    }

    protected Reader bar(){
       // do some operation related with Extractor; then create instance of Reader
       return new RealReader(/*extractor related argument*/);
    }

    private String gar(Reader reader){
        // do something and return String
        return reader.some_string_getter();
    }

    interface Reader { String some_string_getter(); }

    protected static class RealReader implements Reader
    {
       @Override public String some_string_getter() { return "hello from real method"; }
    }

}
```

Junit:

```
package sw_stackoverflow;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
public class CLASSZTest {

   @Test
   public void mockito_can_stub_protected_methods ()
    throws Exception
   {
      final CLASSZ.Reader r = new StubReader("hello from mockito");
      CLASSZ realO = new CLASSZ();
      CLASSZ spyO = spy(realO);
      when(spyO.bar()).thenReturn(r);
      assertEquals("hello from mockito",spyO.foo());
   }

   protected static class StubReader implements CLASSZ.Reader
   {
      final String s;
      StubReader(String s) { this.s = s; }
      @Override public String some_string_getter() { return s; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if your test is in the same package as `CLASSZ`, then package-private is enough.